# Internal and external Microphone not working on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, microphone

I didn't have this issue when I used windows .
Sometime after using Ubuntu 20.04 the microphone input suddenly stopped for both internal and external microphones.
When I try to record it's basically silent when I raise the input volume to maximum in Ubuntu I just hear scratching and weird unclear noises when I talk.

I tried pulse audio and it worked for sometime but now it doesn't work anymore.

How to fix this?

Comment: It is impossible to tell anything. Try to boot from A LiveUSB and check it from there.

Comment: i already checked using windows it works fine

Comment: Check with a LiveUSB. If it works there, then it is some setting you did.